# Webdav with permalink in Wordpress v3.3.1

Tags: permalinks, apache

I've deployed wordpress and I'm using it with postgreSQL, I've configured permalinks successfully, but my webdav folder stoped to work.

When I try to access my webdav folder it prompt to use my login and password, but when I proceed it return me 403 forbidden.

Is there some way to make both work together?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin root@root.com
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride none
        </Directory>
        <Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

<Location /webdav>
    Options Indexes
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/webdav.password
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I´ve found my own answer for this problem, I've edited my /site-avaiable/default/, added `Alias /webdav "/var/www/webdav"` And I've moved my folder to /var/www/webdav/, now its working when I try to access it by using `http://10.0.0.36/webdav`.

Comment: What is "webdav"? What does not work? Sidenote: WP does not support old versions and the community over does not as well. Why don't you update?

Comment: Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV) is an extension of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) that facilitates collaboration between users in editing and managing documents and files stored on World Wide Web servers. A working group of the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) defined [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV).

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found my own answer for this problem, I've edited my `/site-avaiable/default/`, added `Alias /webdav "/var/www/webdav"` And I've moved my folder to `/var/www/webdav/`, now its working when I try to access it by using `http://10.0.0.36/webdav`.